# Adding images to LinearLayout in code in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, center

I have a list of images that I need to show on the page one after another and all that bellow some text. I have LinearLayout in xml of the file where I added the part related to that text (some TextViews). As I need to call service to get image urls I add images to that LinearLayout in code. I use this code to get image using its url and to add it to the layout (in the onPostExecute part of the AsyncTask implementation).

```
/**
     * Download image using image url and show it in ImageView
     */
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
        public DownloadImageTask() {
            super();
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            String urlDisplay = mDocumentUrls.get(mDocumentIdx);
            mDocumentIdx = mDocumentIdx + 1;
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bmp;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // We add a new ImageView to the LinearLayout of the page and set it
            // source to the downloaded image
            ImageView newImageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(convertDpToPx(20), convertDpToPx(5), convertDpToPx(20), 0);

            newImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            mDocumentDetailsLayout.addView(newImageView, params);

            //Next image
            if(mDocumentIdx < mDocumentUrls.size())
                new DownloadImageTask().execute();
        }
    }
```

And this is the xml of the page (the part related to LinearLayout)

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/details_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/splashScreenGray
        android:visibility="gone" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_form_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/splashScreenGray"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"  ...
```

Images are shown on the page, but I have two problems:
1. I can't center them horizontally (prtsc1.png)
2. When my phone is in portrait mode I have this margins (top margin on the first image and margins between images) that I don't have when my phone is in portrait mode (I don't need them) - compare prtsc1.png and prtsc2.png.

[image: prtsc1.png]

[image]

I tried everything, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try to add `android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"` to your `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: Didn't help. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I solved the first problem. I added empty RelativeLayout to the existing LinearLayout and I added my images to that RelativeLayout, but I can't figure out these margins in portrait view.

Comment: I guess you tried to add the same `layout_gravity`attribute to your `scrollview`? I have the same configuration as yours and I don't have this problem. Also, are you sure you use the same xml file in landscape and portrait mode ? If yes, did you try to use a different file in one mode ?

Comment: Are you referring to my second problem?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking maybe if you specify the gravity to `top` you won't have this margin above your image

Comment: If you set 0 to the top arguments of `params.setMargins`, do you still have the margin on top ?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I tried all of this and it didn't helped. And I use the same layout for landscape and portrait.

Comment: Well sorry I can't help you more, let us know if you find a solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help...for u r imageView to getCentrally Aligned...

```
img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Any problem persist please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try Relative layout instead of LinearLayout. LinearLayout has a brain of its own, that is good otherwise but sometimes it can mess things up.

You should change the parameters of the image to align itself below the text

for the second one, if you are using a linearlayout, you should make the width match_parent and padding.